# calculate sum of income with Firestore

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'mm trying to calculate sum of `serviceCost` from Firestore. I managed to get all the docs but it seems that the query calculated only the first cost entered of given month.

Code:

```
firebase
  .firestore()
  .collection("users")
  .doc(uid)
  .collection("confirmed-appointments")
  .get()
  .then((querySnapshot) => {
      let serviceCostTotal = 0; //Will hold currentMonth Total Income.
      let monthNumber = 0;
      let array = [];
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        monthNumber = parseInt(doc.data().month, 10);
        serviceCostTotal =
          serviceCostTotal + parseInt(doc.data().serviceCost, 10); //Calculate Total Month income using this formula
        array[monthNumber - 1] = serviceCostTotal; //Push the income of month X to array in X place
        serviceCostTotal = 0; // after pushing, initialize the sum to 0
      });
```

For example:
I want to calculate the total serviceCost for month 10.

Firestore looks like this:
[image: Firestore]

In the loop I'm trying to take the `serviceCost` of each doc, and push it to array[monthNumber].

The problem is: if i have 2 docs that their value is the same "month: xx" , the loop calculate only the serviceCost value of the first doc.
Meaning that if my sum needs to be 6000, it will be only 2500.

its calculating only this:
[image: 2]

while i have this also:
[image: 3]

Comment: What's wrong with what you have now?  Please edit the question to be clear about what isn't working the way you expect, and how you are observing that.  We should be able to take your code and data and reproduce for ourselves.

Comment: Edited, i hope you can understnad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're explicitly overwriting each element. Try adding to it instead.

```
array[monthNumber - 1] = serviceCostTotal

// Should be
array[monthNumber - 1] = (array[monthNumber - 1] || 0) + serviceCostTotal
```

Edit:
As others have said this code works

```
  let monthNumber = 0;
  let array = [];
  [{ month: 1, serviceCost: 15 },
  { month: 1, serviceCost: 4 },
  { month: 1, serviceCost: 9 },
  { month: 2, serviceCost: 1 },
  { month: 3, serviceCost: 100 }].forEach((doc) => {
    monthNumber = parseInt(doc.month, 10);
    serviceCostTotal =
      serviceCostTotal + parseInt(doc.serviceCost, 10); //Calculate Total Month income using this formula
    array[monthNumber - 1] = (array[monthNumber - 1] || 0) + serviceCostTotal; //Push the income of month X to array in X place
    serviceCostTotal = 0; // after pushing, initialize the sum to 0
  });
  console.log(array);
```

You have to show us how you are validating this and what the actual input and outputs are.

Comment: Still the same outcome :(

Answer (score 0):

As you said you already have the data in the array index so you can do like this

```js
const querySnapshot = [{
  month: 10,
  serviceCost: 2500
}, {
  month: 10,
  serviceCost: 3500
}, {
  month: 11,
  serviceCost: 1000
}];

const array = [];
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  const monthNumber = parseInt(doc.month, 10);
  array[monthNumber - 1] = (array[monthNumber - 1] || 0) + parseInt(doc.serviceCost, 10);
});

console.log(array);
```

You basically check if whether there is something in that index of that month and add it or use the serviceCostTotal that you calculated

Comment: I still get the same outcome, its weird. do i need to remove the serviceCostTotal = 0 ?

Comment: Does it have only the first value ?

Comment: I made a snippet, it should work, i just remove the data() part

Comment: I Tried, nothing came out :(

Comment: Updated my snipped actually, you have to add the data() part in month and serviceCost

Comment: Cant figure out why its not working, i will just throw my computer from the window

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223309/discussion-between-guruparan-giritharan-and-osher-revach).